# Best way to create maven project to upload missing jars in central repository

Tags: maven, jar, repository, installation, proguard

ProGuard version 4.5, 4.5.1 and 4.6 have been released, but unfortunately, the corresponding maven artifacts have not been released in central repository:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
    <artifactId>proguard</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version> <-- This is the limit
<scope>runtime</scope> </dependency>
```

I have left a message on Proguard's [forum](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/forums/forum/182455/topic/4555163) for more information. I am considering releasing them myself since Eric Lafortune mentioned he is not involved with maven anymore.

Instead of recompiling the code, I was wondering whether it might be possible to create a maven project to install existing jars (available from sourceforge) into the central repository. This is different than installing external jars in a local repository.

How can I configure my pom.xml to achieve this assuming those jars are available in my local repository? Is this possible?

The next step would be to use Sonatype's repository as a stepstone to release the artifacts into central repository.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. The `mvn install` is a command line tool and maven central repository is just a Version Controlled system, you need to commit the new jar's into it, but not through pom

Comment: There is manual option in Sonatype to load artifacts. May be that's the way forward...

Comment: You can use maven deploy plugin (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) to publish artifacts to external repository, assuming you have the rights.